# Spark py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o718.showString

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I am running python API on Spark(pySPark) to build models on cloudera cluster.

I created a batch file to submit the job. The job runs successfully except for the last step of displaying the result of the dataframe - '`step3_final.show()`', it throws an error.

PFB the error message, that I received in the logs

```
step3_final.show(6)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p1876.1944/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 257, in show
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p1876.1944/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p1876.1944/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p1876.1944/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o718.showString.
```

Can anyone please help me understand the error message. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try count() action so that we can be sure that whether its is display error or there is a problem with some operations in the data frame

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo - All the previous step which includes count(), filter() etc. run in the code this error only occurs at the last stage of displaying the result

Answer (score 0):

this may be because of the encoding issue just add this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in your python script at the top of the code if you are running the solution using spark submit else

```
import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

do let me know if this helps